# Should Show 404 error when user provide invalid url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing, rescue

Suppose my website URL is http://localhost:3000,
But when user manually type http://localhost:3000/orders, he should be redirected to root_path or some other path because this url is only valid after session is created.
and I am getting
**NoMethodError in OrdersController#index**

**undefined method `orders' for nil:NilClass**
[image]

Comment: before downvote the question, please specify the reason, so that I will improve that while asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure user will be redirected to root url you have to use some 
`before_action` (`before_filter` in Rails 3) to your controller.

For example if you're using [Device gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication you have to add to your controller:

`before_action :authenticate_user!` ([more details...](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers))

If you have your own authentication system you have to implement manually something like device's `authenticate_user!` method to set current_user.

If I correctly understood your issue you should get the idea.

Comment: Adding before filter raises another problem, that's why i ma not using that.

Comment: Well this means you have incorrect code in your before_filter method or it receiving incorrect params or your `Device` configuration is incorrect (in case you use it), so that's another question you need to solve. Because technically reason of your error is - `current_user` was not set and equals to `nil`, so you have to set it somewhere. And it would be straightforward and obvious to reuse it in multiple places of your project with help of `before_filter` in which you authenticate your user and set to `current_user`. There are not enough information given here to tell something more precise.

Comment: it is just because I am not using devise routes,and it always moves to devise/sign_in path but my sign_in path is different.